# Import json data into elastic search

Tags: json, curl, elasticsearch

Im currently trying to import json data into elastic search.I have installed elastic search v2.2.1 in windows7 & trying to import json data into elasticsearch. But Im unable to import the same. I have checked various posts and they are specifying to execute the curl command. Below are the steps that I have tried

- Tried to execute the below curl command via command prompt.But got a message that 'curl command is not recognised as an internal or external command'.
- Installed cygwin and tried to execute the curl command, got a message'-bash: curl: command not found'.
- I also tried to install sense chrome plugin, but unable to download the plugin and found that the plugin is no longer available.
- I also installed the inquisitor plugin for elastic search, but looks like it helps to validate the query and does not help in importing the data into elastic search.

Any help on this is much appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Download Curl from  official  site: 
https://curl.haxx.se/download.html

Answer (score 0):

For curl in windows you could try the download link [here](https://curl.haxx.se/download.html)

The other way to use in windows is to use the `Sense`, which is a Kibana app. You can install it from [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/sense/current/installing.html)

The Sense app replaces the Chrome plugin

Comment: Thanks for the response Hugo. I tried installing sense. But got the below error in command prompt "Client request error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN download.elastic.co:443". I also have the latest tar.gz for sense downloaded seperately but not able to install it . can u please help in installing the same. Thanks in advance